# FloatingActionButton does not float at the bottom right corner in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a simple Birthday reminder app. For that I use a RecyclerView container, and so far my project is looking fine. However, I have meet a problem.
I would like to have a FloatingActionButton at the bottom right corner of the screen in order to add new birthdays to the list.

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/mainToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/birthday_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

this is how my floatingActionButton should somehow look

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/add_birthday"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:src="@drawable/add_geb"
            app:fabSize="normal" />
```

Does anyone know how I can float my button in the bottom right corner?

This is how it looks now:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/mainToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/birthday_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_birthday"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/add_geb"
        app:fabSize="normal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where is the fab in your xml?

Comment: And if the entire layout, missing only fab, there is no reason to have the LinearLayout inside coordinatorlayout

Comment: First i treid to put it after the linear layout. but then it just positioned itself in the middle of the screen, and was way to big.

Comment: Refer to my answer below

Comment: Okay I just saw the fab attribute, remove the coordinator layout and it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my answer after updated your question.

If that is the entirety of your layout, remove the coordinator layout as it is unnecessary, the attribute layout_gravity should position the fab in a linear layout.

Comment: i did remove the coordinatory layout, and everthing seems to work, but sadly the fab does not show up in the design...